# How to do vector-matrix multiplication with conditions?

Tags: python

I want to obtain a list (or array, doesn't matter) of A from the following formula:

```
A_i = X_(k!=i) * S_(k!=i) * X'_(k!=i)
```

where:

X is a vector (and X' is the transpose of X), S is a matrix, and the subscript k is defined as {k=1,2,3,...n| k!=i}.

```
X = [x1, x2, ..., xn]

S = [[s11,s12,...,s1n],
     [s21,s22,...,s2n]
     [... ...  ... ..]
     [sn1,sn2,...,snn]]
```

I take the following as an example:

```
X = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5]  

S = [[0.4,0.1,0.3,0.5],
     [2,1.5,2.4,0.6]
     [0.4,0.1,0.3,0.5]
     [2,1.5,2.4,0.6]]
```

So, eventually, I would get a list of four values for A.

I did this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5])
s = np.matrix([[0.4,0.1,0.3,0.5],[1,2,1.5,2.4,0.6],[0.4,0.1,0.3,0.5],[1,2,1.5,2.4,0.6]])

for k in range(x) if k!=i 
A = (x.dot(s)).dot(np.transpose(x))

print (A)
```

I am confused with how to use a conditional 'for' loop. Could you please help me to solve it? Thanks.

EDIT:
Just to explain more. If you take i=1, then the formula will be:

```
  A_1 = X_(k!=1) * S_(k!=1) * X'_(k!=1)
```

So any array (or value) associated with subscript 1 will be deleted in X and S. like:

```
X = [0.2,0.3,0.5]  

S = [[1.5,2.4,0.6]
     [0.1,0.3,0.5]
     [1.5,2.4,0.6]]
```

Comment: `A = (x.dot(s)).dot(np.transpose(x))` throughout a loop is only gonna get you the last computed value into `A` (unless, of course, you use `k` somewhere within this computation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: correctly calculate A_i

Step 2: collect them into A

---

I assume what you want to calculate is

[image]

An easy way to do so is to mask away the entries using masked arrays. This way we don't need to delete or copy any matrixes.

```
# sample
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
s = np.diag([4,5,6,7])

# we will use masked arrays to remove k=i
vec_mask = np.zeros_like(x)
matrix_mask = np.zeros_like(s)

i = 0  # start

# set masks
vec_mask[i] = 1
matrix_mask[i] = matrix_mask[:,i] = 1

s_mask = np.ma.array(s, mask=matrix_mask)
x_mask = np.ma.array(x, mask=vec_mask)

# reduced product, remember using np.ma.inner instead np.inner
Ai = np.ma.inner(np.ma.inner(x_mask, s_mask), x_mask.T)

vec_mask[i] = 0
matrix_mask[i] = matrix_mask[:,i] = 0
```

As terms of `0` don't add to the sum, we actually can ignore masking the matrix and just mask the vector:

```
# we will use masked arrays to remove k=i
mask = np.zeros_like(x)

i = 0  # start

# set masks
mask[i] = 1

x_mask = np.ma.array(x, mask=mask)

# reduced product
Ai = np.ma.inner(np.ma.inner(x_mask, s), x_mask.T)

# unset mask
mask[i] = 0
```

---

The final step is to assemble `A` out of the `A_i`s, so in total we get

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
s = np.diag([4,5,6,7])

mask = np.zeros_like(x)
x_mask = np.ma.array(x, mask=mask)
A = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    x_mask.mask[i] = 1
    Ai = np.ma.inner(np.ma.inner(x_mask, s), x_mask.T)
    A.append(Ai)
    x_mask.mask[i] = 0
A_vec = np.array(A)
```

Comment: I am getting this error for your code:     for k in range(x):
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: sorry, should be `range(len(x))`.

Comment: I have edited the question for i. If you check the first formula, it is the subscript of A.

Comment: Note that `np.inner` ignores the mask. You need to use `np.ma.inner` instead.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a matrix/vector product using loops will be rather slow in Python. Therefore, I suggest to actually delete the rows/columns/elements at the given index and perform the fast built-in dot product without any explicit loops:

```
i = 0  # don't forget Python's indices are zero-based

x_ = np.delete(X, i)  # remove element
s_ = np.delete(S, i, axis=0)  # remove row
s_ = np.delete(s_, i, axis=1)  # remove column

result = x_.dot(s_).dot(x_)  # no need to transpose a 1-D array
```